# Xmpp server to server using protobuf

Tags: xmpp, openfire, protocol-buffers

I am tasked with creating a text messaging system with low bandwidth server to server connections. The other developers already use protobuf to send data for other parts of the system between these same server locations, and it would be helpful to continue that trend for the text messaging portion. Server to client connections are not bandwidth constrained. It would be great to be able to use an unmodified chat client and openfire xmpp server.

What is better to program in this situation, a component for openfire or a transport for Kraken?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling [XEP-138](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0138.html) compression on the server-to-server link?  Even if OpenFire doesn't support XEP-138, it will be easy to add, and should provide better results that almost any naive translation to protobufs.

Comment: If this is compressing xml, won't it still be larger than a protobuf message?  The decision makers on this project really want the smallest data transmissions possible.

Comment: This can only be proven with data on *your* expected data stream, but I think you'll be **shocked** how well the XML compresses.  Compressed XML will likely beat uncompressed protobufs by a good amount, at the cost of higher CPU on either side, but with the advantage of extensibility.

Comment: @Hoe, understood that it depends on the data, but do you have anything to backup that assertion?

Comment: I've seen a bunch of data from Dave Cridland (@DwdDave on twitter) where he tried different compression approaches.  Maybe he still has the slides.  However, I encourage you to build your own protocol and implementations of clients and a server from scratch on top of protobuf.  It will be a fun project.